# Update a popup window textview dynamically without dismissing and recreating it

Tags: android, popup

I'm trying to update a textview in my popup window as changes happen in my program.  This displays a popup with the first assigned "firstChar" when an option is chosen.  However, when the next option is chosen, it does not update to the new option, just continues showing the original option.

If I dismiss and redisplay the popup, it flickers and I don't want that. Making a new popup window each time causes a memory leak.

Any ideas?

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popupText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="A"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="50sp" />
```

In my ListAdapter:

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_custom_layout, null);
TextView popUpText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.popupText);
popUpText.setText(Character.toString(firstChar));
popUp.setContentView(layout);
popUp.showAtLocation(row, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
popUp.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you ordering your code like that ?

`popUp.setContentView(layout);
popUpText.setText(Character.toString(firstChar));`